# trying to create an array of objects given 2 arrays + map

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary

I have the following 2 arrays here:

```
  > chNameArr
[ 'chanel1',
  'chanel2',
  'chanel3',
  'chanel4',
  'chanel5',
  'chanel6',
  'chanel7' ]
```

and here:

```
   > a
[ 'channelName'
  'status',
  'connections',
  'socketIds',
  'lastRun',
  'numberOfRuns',
  'timeout' ]
```

what I am trying to achieve is the following objects per channel in an array where   `channelName` from `a` get the value from `chNameArr` but the rest of 'a' gets an empty string

```
 file=[{"channelName":"chanel1","status":"", "connections":"", "socketIds":"", "lastRun":"", "numberOfRuns":"", "timeout":""},
 .
 .
 .
        {"channelName":"chanel7","status":"", "connections":"", "socketIds":"", "lastRun":"", "numberOfRuns":"", "timeout":""}]
```

this is my attempt

```
   > chNameArr.map(function(d){return {channelName:d}})
[ { channelName: 'chanel1' },
  { channelName: 'chanel2' },
  { channelName: 'chanel3' },
  { channelName: 'chanel4' },
  { channelName: 'chanel5' },
  { channelName: 'chanel6' },
  { channelName: 'chanel7' } ]
```

Comment: So what's the problem? Do you know how to iterate over an array? And how to add properties to an object? That's the only thing you'd need to know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
chNameArr.map(function(d) {
  result = {};
  result[a[0]] = d;
  for (var i=1; i<a.length; i++) {
    result[a[i]] = "";
  }
  return result;
})
```

There is no one-liner to solve this problem in general, although if you don't actually need to use the array `a` you could manually construct `{channelName:d, status: "", ...}` in your original map.

Comment: tks your function is perfect as I can then add to the `a` array and it will still work where as manually constructing it won't be as dynamic